# Obtaining Flow ID from a Bash script

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-id, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

I need assistance with my Bash script for creating a link to a flow in Flow Builder that I want to open. I am encountering an issue where I am getting a null value from the `$response` variable. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and if there is a way to obtain the flow ID without using the Tooling API.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

```bash
process_flow_files() {
  # ...

  # Authenticating and creating the scratch org
  # ...

  # Retrieving the flow ID
  LABEL="label"
  QUERY=$(printf "SELECT+Id,MasterLabel+FROM+Flow__Flow+WHERE+Status+=+'Active'+AND+MasterLabel+=+'%s'" "$LABEL")

  response=$(curl -s "$INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v52.0/tooling/query/?q=$QUERY" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-PrettyPrint:1")

 
  echo "$response"

  # Extracting the flow ID and creating the flow link
  FLOW_ID=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.records[0].Id')
  FLOW_LINK="https://$SCRATCH_ORG_URL/lightning/r/Flow/$FLOW_ID/view"
  echo "Flow Link: $FLOW_LINK"

  # ...
}
```